# Returning an anonymous list to model type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

[1] I want to pass the anonymous list to the view but I'm finding it difficult
please help me with the code:

I have the Model as :

```
namespace OpenOrderFramework.Models
{
    [Bind(Exclude = "ID")]
    public class Item
    {
        private static NLog.Logger logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        [Key]
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Catagorie:")]
        public int CatagorieId { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = " Item name cannot be empty, this is required")]
        [DisplayName("Item Name")]
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("GRC TAG")]
        public string GRCTag { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Location:")]
        public int LocationId { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Item Name:")]
        public int itemnameId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Quantity of item in a Location is required!")]
        [DisplayName("Quantity in Store:")]
        public int ItemQty { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
```

controller is:

```
private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        // GET: Items
        public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
        {                      
            ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
            ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "Name";
            ViewBag.PriceSortParm = sortOrder == "Name" ? "Loc_desc" : "Location";
            IEnumerable<Item> items = db.Items;
           var ko= (from r in items.GroupBy(x => new { x.Catagorie, x.ItemName })
                                  .Select(g => new 
                                  {
                                      Catagorie = g.Key.Catagorie.Name,
                                      ItemName = g.Key.ItemName,
                                      ItemQty = g.Sum(s => s.ItemQty),
                                      Location = g.First().Location.Name

                                  })
                         select r).ToList();


                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchString))
                {
                    items = items.Where(s => s.ItemName.Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                                               || s.Catagorie.Name.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()) ||
                                               s.Location.Name.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())).ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 20);
                    //}

                }
                else
                {
                    items = items.ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 10);
                }

            return View(ko.ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 20));

        }
```

and the View is :

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<OpenOrderFramework.Models.Item>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@using PagedList;

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Catagory
        </th>
       <th>
            Item Name.
        </th>
 <th>
            Quantity.
        </th>

 @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <font color="RED">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Catagorie.Name)
                </font>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ItemName)
            </td>            
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ItemQty)
            </td>
```

[2] please help me with the code and return the filtered list to the view .
tried so many but not working.. got this error

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'PagedList.PagedList'1[<>f__AnonymousType7`4[System.String,System.String,System.Int32,System.String]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'PagedList.IPagedList'1[OpenOrderFramework.Models.Item]'

please help me with the code to to return the list of anonymous . I don't understand what to do . please anyone to show me a sample code to follow and make correction and show me how it'll work with the model and all?

Comment: the error clearly states that you have to pass PagedList.IPagedList<OpenOrderFramework.Models.Item> to the view

Comment: i dont understand, help me please. make the correction for me

Comment: can you make a fiddle of what you have done? https://dotnetfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

Your code :

```
  var ko= (from r in items.GroupBy(x => new { x.Catagorie, x.ItemName })
                              .Select(g => new 
                              {
                                  Catagorie = g.Key.Catagorie.Name,
                                  ItemName = g.Key.ItemName,
                                  ItemQty = g.Sum(s => s.ItemQty),
                                  Location = g.First().Location.Name

                              })
                     select r).ToList();
```

is generating a collection of anonymous type. Create a model  which has these properties and pass that model into view as a PagedList.

```
public class MyObj
{
    public string Catagorie { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public int ItemQty { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

Now in Linq query:

```
var ko= (from r in items.GroupBy(x => new { x.Catagorie, x.ItemName })
                              .Select(g => new MyObj()
                              {
                                  Catagorie = g.Key.Catagorie.Name,
                                  ItemName = g.Key.ItemName,
                                  ItemQty = g.Sum(s => s.ItemQty),
                                  Location = g.First().Location.Name

                              })
                     select r).ToList();
```

And in your view:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<MyObj>
```

So conclusion here is to avoid passing anonymous type and pass your custom model in PagedList.

Hope this will help you.